# Angular How to obtain onselect event

Tags: angularjs

I am displaying some data in a smart-table component(using `angular`). The last column is a select element. What i want to do is plug-in to the "`on-select`" change event and do something with the data displayed in the row.

Here is my [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/CxCQ2eJXj9PUeCCVHoi6?p=preview) :

What i want to achieve is displayed in the comment

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to create a Dropdown list its better to use ng-options than ng-repeat.

```
<select ng-options="x.data for x in myItems"> 
</select>
```

Because the ngRepeat directive repeats a block of HTML code for each item in an array, it can be used to create options in a dropdown list, but the ngOptions directive was made especially for filling a dropdown list with options, and has at least one important advantage:

Dropdowns made with ng-options allows the selected value to be an object, while dropdowns made from ng-repeat has to be a string.

Add ng-change, as well as the required ng-model, and you pass on the ng-model variable into ng-change, if you need to access its value:

```
<select ng-change="handleChange(selectedRow)" ng-model="selectedRow" ng-options="x.data for x in myItems"> 
</select>
```

Then in our controller:

```
$scope.handleChange = function(row){
    //here take action or do whatever you want to. if you want to access the value, you do it through 'row' here, e.g. console.log(row)


}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want trigger function on click on any element use `ng-click`. It can be used as attribute of element. You can call any function and pass arguments.

```
<div ng-repeat="myItem in myItems" ng-click="clicked(myItem.data)">{{myItem.data}}</div>
```

Check [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/vihdXCWtc7ttstxlZ3ZY?p=preview) to see how it works in your `ng-repeat`.

It works, but as it stated in another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37785804/4989081):

> If you want to create a Dropdown list angular its better to use ng-option then ng-repeat.